# Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $f(x)$ defined in R.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

I need to prove the following,
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions defined in R. Suppose that $|f_{n+1}(x)−
f_n(x)| ≤ \frac {n^2}{1+2^n}$
for all x ∈ R and for all $n ≥ 1$.

Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some continuous
function $f(x)$ defined in R.

Right, I am trying to prove that it is Uniformly Cauchy and this is what I have done until now:

Let $f_m$ be a sequence of continuous functions on R such that for all $m, m>n$, and let $\varepsilon >0$ 
then for 
$$|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|$$
$$=|f_m(x)-f_{m-1}(x)+...+f_{n¬1}(x)-f_n(x)|$$
$$\leq |f_m(x)-f_{m-1}(x)|+...+|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)| $$
$$\leq |f_m(x)-f_{m-1}(x)|+...+ \frac {n^2}{1+2^n}$$

I don't know how to continue from there. What value should $\varepsilon$ take such that there exist some N belonging to natural numbers $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|< \varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see if we can get an upper bound that is easier to manipulate.

Let $a_n = {n^2 \over 1+2^n}$, then ${a_{n+1} \over a_n} = (1+{1 \over n})^2 {2^{-n} + 1 \over 2^{-n} + 2}$ and $\lim_n {a_{n+1} \over a_n} = {1 \over 2}$.

So there is some $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we have ${a_{n+1} \over a_n} \le {3 \over 4}$
and so $a_n \le ({ 3 \over 4})^{n-N} a_N$.

Then for $n \ge N$ you have $|f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x)| \le ({ 3 \over 4})^{n} a_N ({ 3 \over 4})^{-N} $.

Then
$|f_{n+p}(x)-f_n(x)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} ({ 3 \over 4})^{n} a_N ({ 3 \over 4})^{-N} \le (4  a_N ({ 3 \over 4})^{-N}) ({ 3 \over 4})^{n}$.

It follows from this that $f_n(x)$ is Cauchy and hence converges to some $f(x)$. Letting $p \to \infty$, we get
$|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le (4  a_N ({ 3 \over 4})^{-N}) ({ 3 \over 4})^{n}$.

Continuity then follows from uniform convergence.

Comment: why do you specifically say that there is some $n \geq N$ for which we have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \leq \frac{3}{4}$? Why specifically $\frac{3}{4}$? For example, if you changed $\frac{3}{4}$ with $\frac{2}{3}$ the proof would still work right?

Comment: @kemb: Yes. You just need some $\lambda <1$ so that $\lambda^n \to 0$.

Comment: great just making sure